# What is error #668269003 on Google Play developer console?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to upload a new version of my app. When I upload the apk and then hit Publish now to production,

it shows me

> "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (668269003)"

I tried searching on Google but couldn't find any valuable and helpful information. Has anybody got the same error?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/wZdGu5CowIA

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, I checked this. The user had a similar problem when he uploaded debug version of his app. But I'm uploading release version of my app.

Comment: This occurred to me when I switched from the new Google play Beta version to the classic mode. Had to go to the home page(main dashboard) of the classic mode page and refresh the site. After that, I was able to go to the app dashboard and continue the app submission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would you use '>' or any special char on your new release text? On my situation when I remove '>' char it was corrected.

Comment: Surprising bug. It was `–` symbol in my case

Comment: same issue for me too :(

Comment: Thanks... It's too weird that google didn't even give a clue about it.

Answer (score 9):

After one hour, logged out and in after that and resubmitted the APK and it was working. Really don't know what the problem was but it seems that Google fixed it.

Comment: I also logged out and logged back in right away and it fixed the issue. This was when coming back to the console after a weekend away from it, so I think the session may have timed out but the front end didn't make me log in again.

Comment: My error occured while sending an invite to a user, logged out and logged in and it worked.

Comment: Logout and Login instantly solved the error! Thanks! :)